# How to publish NX library with its dependencies bundled?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, tsconfig, nrwl-nx

This issue seems to be all over GitHub's NX repository, however I was not able to find any working solution there.

My workspace contains two **buildable** libraries: `ui/avatar` and `ui/icon` and one **publishable** library, called `bar`

The idea would be to use `ui/avatar` and `ui/icon` as internal monorepo libraries (e.g. these can be imported in the apps directly) but I also want to encapsulate these 2 buildable libs into `bar` and publish `bar` as a npm package so that external consumers can benefit from it.

Here's a general overview of the file structure:

```
libs
 ┣ external
 ┃ ┗ bar
 ┃ ┃ ┣ src
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ lib
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ external-bar.module.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ ng-package.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ package.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ project.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ tsconfig.json
 ┣ ui
 ┃ ┣ avatar
 ┃ ┃ ┣ src
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ lib
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ avatar
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ avatar.component.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ ui-avatar.module.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ index.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ ng-package.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ package.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ project.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ tsconfig.json
 ┃ ┗ icon
 ┃ ┃ ┣ src
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ lib
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ icon
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ icon.component.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ ui-icon.module.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ index.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ ng-package.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ package.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ project.json
 ┃ ┃ ┗ tsconfig.json
```

That initial part, works.
I'm able to import `ui/avatar` into `bar` and generate the `@blue/bar` package. The problem is that the generated `package.json` of `@blue/bar` looks as follows:

```
{
  "name": "@blue/bar",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^14.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.1.0",
    "@blue/ui-avatar": "0.0.1" <-- this!!
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "module": "esm2020/blue-bar.mjs",
  "es2020": "esm2020/blue-bar.mjs",
  "esm2020": "esm2020/blue-bar.mjs",
  "typings": "index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    "./package.json": {
      "default": "./package.json"
    },
    ".": {
      "types": "./index.d.ts",
      "es2020": "./esm2020/blue-bar.mjs",
      "esm2020": "./esm2020/blue-bar.mjs",
      "default": "./esm2020/blue-bar.mjs"
    }
  },
  "sideEffects": false
}
```

The generated package, expects `ui/avatar` to be a an existing *npm package* (and thus to exist in some registry) but what I really need is to bundle the `ui/avatar` as part of the **@blue/bar** package and not as a third party dependency.

I have tried to adjust the `tsconfig.json` file of the `bar` lib to somehow try to [resolve the dependencies locally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) (using `paths`) but it doesn't seems to work.

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declarationMap": false,
    "paths": {
      "@blue/ui-avatar": ["libs/ui/avatar/src/index.ts"],
      "@blue/ui-icon": ["libs/ui/icon/src/index.ts"]
    }
  }
```

Any hints would be greately appreciated :)

Comment: Looks like it's an open issue https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/4620

Comment: @guzmanoj did you managed to solve that?
I'm facing the same problem

Comment: I did actually. Need to find some time to explain the solution or even better publish the custom executor...

Comment: @OrShalmayev https://www.npmjs.com/package/@altack/nx-bundlefy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually and considering that the issue remains unsolved, I decided to write a custom Nx executor to achieve the job. Will share it here so that maybe it could help others.

You can install the executor via npm from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@altack/nx-bundlefy

Also, the source code is available in Github: https://github.com/altack/nx-bundlefy